# Check constraint on digits in a string in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table column p which should only include entries like Cash_1, Cash_2, Cash_3 till Cash_36.
I am not able to use this as a check constraint.
I tried check((p>='Cash_1' AND p<='Cash_36') AND p like 'Cash_%')
but i am not able to enter the data like Cash_4 or Cash_5.
Even if i do so i am not able to ensure that the string after 'Cash_' is a digit
Plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine two checks for this.

You need a regular expression to verify that the value `Cash_` is followed by one or two digits:

```
check (p ~ 'Cash_[0-9]{1,2}')
```

However this also allows e.g. `Cash_00` or `Cash_99`. So you need another condition that checks if the number is between 1 and 36

```
check (p ~ 'Cash_[0-9]{1,2}' and regexp_replace(p, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int between 1 and 36)
```

`regexp_replace(p, '[^0-9]', '')` removes all non-digits from the string and the result is then cast to an integer using `::int`. This number is then checked for the proper interval.

Comment: select regexp_replace('abcd123','[^0-9]',''); gives output bcd123 in postgres. Expected output:123

Comment: @user3398648: sorry, forgot the `'g'` option, corrected